# wpf webBrowser NavigateToString script error

Tags: wpf, browser, mathjax

I want to use the Wpf webBrowser control to render math equations.
I've downloaded MathJax, and included it in my Visual studio project.

I've tryed to load one of the [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) example. This is the html code i'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax MathML Test Page</title>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2010-2012 Design Science, Inc. -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>
When
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mi>a</mi><mo>&#x2260;</mo><mn>0</mn>
</math>,
there are two solutions to
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mi>a</mi><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
  <mo>+</mo> <mi>b</mi><mi>x</mi>
  <mo>+</mo> <mi>c</mi> <mo>=</mo> <mn>0</mn>
</math>
and they are
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mi>x</mi> <mo>=</mo>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow>
        <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
        <mi>b</mi>
        <mo>&#x00B1;</mo>
        <msqrt>
          <msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
          <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
          <mn>4</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi>
        </msqrt>
      </mrow>
      <mrow> <mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi> </mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working fine with the following code:

```
string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/test-1.html", curDir)));
```

But if i try this code:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\test-1.html");
this.webBrowser1.NavigateToString(s);
```

i get a Script Error:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line:    1
Char:    1
Error:   Syntax Error
Code:    0
URL:     about:MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full
```

What's wrong? It would be really helpful to use something similar to the last code, so i can avoid to save a file just to load it...

Answer (score 0):

Note that the URL in the error is `about:MathJax-Reduced/unpacked...`, which is an `about` URL not the `file://` URL that you had in the first case.  I suspect that is the cause of the problem.  That suggests that the `NavigateToString` function is using `about:blank` or a similar URL as the base URL for the page, so MathJax is getting the wrong path to itself.  Note that you lose the actual page location when reading it from the file and loading it as a string.  That means you may have to load MathJax from an absolute URL rather than a relative one (i.e., include the `file://` and path to the `MathJax-Reduced` directory).

Comment: I have tryed to add the absolute path:

`file://C$/Users/Davide/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/Test-MathJax-1/Test-MathJax-1/bin/Debug/MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full`
\nIt doesn't render the math.

Comment: I have tryed to use:
`file://127.0.0.1/C$/Users/Davide/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/Test-MathJax-1/Test-MathJax-1/bin/Debug/MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_‌​HTMLorMML-full`  
this give me the error:  
`An error has occured in the script on this page.  
Line: 181  
Char: 7  
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'img': objects is null or undefined  
Code: 0  
URL: file://127.0.0.1/C$/Users/Davide/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/Test-MathJax-1/Test-MathJax-1/bin/Debug/MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/jax/output/HTML-CSS/imageFonts.js`

Comment: The `MathJax-Reduced` suggests that you have removed part of the MathJax distribution, probably the image fonts (the `font/HTML-CSS/TeX/png` folder), as these form a large part of the space taken by MathJax.  Note that the failure is occurring while trying to load the image font package, which suggests that they have been removed.  If you don't install the image fonts, you need to inform MathJax of that by setting `imageFont:null` in the `"HTML-CSS"` section of your  configuration.

Comment: I have included the fonts folder, the problem is the use of the absolute path. Look at the following message i've seen while loading the page: `File failed to load: file://127.0.0.1/C$/Users/Davide/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/Test-MathJax-1/Test-MathJax-1/bin/Debug/MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/../fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/png/unpacked/imagedata.js`

Comment: The portion of the path `MathJax-Reduced/unpacked/../fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX‌​/png/unpacked/imagedata.js` is correct.  Is the initial portion correct?  If the `../` is bothering you, that is to remove the `unpacked` directory, since the fonts are in the main directory.  I'm a little surprised that you are getting image fonts in the first place, though. Are you using Firefox?  Firefox with `file://` URL's is the only case left where that occurs.  An easy solution to that is to install the MathJax OTF fonts in your system fonts folder instead.